# SQL_Teradata_RegExp

Tags: sql, qregexp, teradata

Хелп!
Есть две таблицы, одна с с сотней регулярных выражений типа ^\d+$, и вторая с кучей текста. Как написать запрос SQL, чтоб регулярка проверяла по тексту и напротив каждой регулярки записывался count(*) найденных?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(*)
FROM regexps t1
JOIN texts t2 ON t2.txt LIKE t1.regexp
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Но работать будет... скажем так - неспешно.

Comment: Спасибо! Но возвращает ничего :(

Comment: В таблице regexps лежит ^\d+$, в таблице texts лежит 1234, все это в формате varchar. Запрос запускал в Teradata SQL Assistant

Comment: И так же в таблице regexps лежит ^\D+$, в таблице texts лежит Илья, все это в формате varchar. Запрос запускал в Teradata SQL Assistant

Comment: @Ilya Я не нашёл навскидку справку по операторам терадаты... может, там LIKE использует простейшие шаблоны, а для проверки по Вашим паттернам нужен какой-нить REGEXP? Создайте тест-таблицы, по 2-3 записи, попробуйте `SELECT *, t2.txt LIKE t1.patt AS testing_result FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2` и заставьте выдавать правильные результаты проверки в вычисляемом столбце, а потом используйте правильное выражение в условии связывания моего запроса.

Comment: @Ilya Попробуйте использовать [REGEXP_SIMILAR](https://docs.teradata.com/r/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/fwqgzZuhAvOXLKUu0kUfJQ)

Comment: О, спасибо! Вот такая конструкция работает SELECT * FROM texts t1 WHERE REGEXP_SIMILAR ( txt, '\D+$') = 1;